# Adding Windows account to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to add the window controllerservices account to the SQL server and give it right to start and stop trace. Can some body please let me know how can this be done. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE LOGIN [domain\account] FROM WINDOWS;
GRANT ALTER TRACE TO [domain\account];
```